# Issue with sorting a dict by value, when output wanted is in format (value, key)

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, lambda

I'm a beginner, and need help sorting a dict. This is what I've tried:

```
english_spanish = {"hi": "hola", "thanks": "gracias", "yes": "si", "no": "no"}

for word in english_spanish:
sort = sorted(english_spanish.items(), key=lambda english_spanish: english_spanish[1])
sort = [' '.join(tups) for tups in sort]
for tuple in sort:
    print(tuple)
```

It does the sort correctly, but the output is

```
thanks gracias
hi hola
no no
yes si
```

I'd want the output to be in reverse order, but since the sort outputs a tuple I'm having a hard time reversing it.

One more thing, it's required to use `key=lambda` in this code, I know of other ways of doing this sort but the lambda part is confusing me a bit.

Comment: Did you read [the examples](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)? Basically  `key` is just a function that returns the thing you want to sort on. So write a function (not necessarily a lambda) that returns the second item from a tuple... and it will sort on that.

Comment: `sort = [' '.join(tups[::-1]) for tups in sort]`?

Comment: @Krrr That's exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: `sort = [f'{value} {key}' for key, value in sort]` would be another of many options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know in which order you want to sort the dictionary, but I'll try to explain everything:

When you run `english_spanish.items()` you get a list of tuples.

```
[(key1, value1), (key2, value2) ... ]
```

The `key lambda` in `sorted` method specify on which element of the tuples you want to sort. If you set `lambda x: x[0]`, it means that you are sorting using the first value of the tuples `(key1, value1)` as sorting key ( basically `key1`, `key2` etc). If you use  `lambda x: x[1]` you are using instead the second value of the tuples as sorting key (basically `value1`, `value2`, etc) [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions).

If you want your tuples list with values as `[(value1, key1), ...]` instead of `[(key1, value1), ...]` you can do something like:

```
sort = sorted([v[::-1] for v in english_spanish.items()], key=lambda x: x[0])
```

But I think it is better to sort using the key parameter to specify on which value of the tuple you want to sort, and than change the order directly for your print

```
english_spanish = {"hi": "hola", "thanks": "gracias", "yes": "si", "no": "no"}

sort = sorted(english_spanish.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
sort = [' '.join(tups[::-1]) for tups in sort]
for tuple in sort:
    print(tuple)
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this reverses the order of the sort, but I want to reverse the order in which the words in the tuple appear, so without the reverse=True and in the format ```(value1, key1)```

Comment: It is not necessary, but I'll update with an example fo what you want to do

Comment: Thank you! The ```[::-1]``` was what I needed, I didn't know that existed! The other examples were really useful as well, I feel like I understand the problem a lot better now! :)